# Android, when reopen a service the images Views show wrong

Tags: android, android-studio, service, view, imagebutton

First sorry for my English

I try to start a service, this contain a layout inflated with some imageButtons, this images have shapes for shadow. 
For first time to start service the images are showing  fine, but if I stop the service and reopening them, without close the activity, the images display wrong, especially the alpha of shadows, like if images are duplicated. I try to clear all images onDestroy() but I've still the same problem.
Pls any help is welcome. Thanks!

Main Activity

```
// Create the start service button, which tries to show an interstitial when clicked and start floating service.
    mStartServiceButton = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.start_service_button));
    mStartServiceButton.setEnabled(false);
    mStartServiceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showInterstitial();
            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServiceFloating.class));
        }
    });

    // Create the stop service button, which tries to stop floating service
    mStopServiceButton = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_service_button));
    mStopServiceButton.setEnabled(false);
    mStopServiceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServiceFloating.class));
            showInterstitial();
        }
    });
```

Service code

```
    public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            floatingView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_floating, null);


     lightButton = (ImageButton) floatingView.findViewById(R.id.screen_button);
            playButton = (ImageButton) floatingView.findViewById(R.id.play_button);
            stopButton = (ImageButton) floatingView.findViewById(R.id.stop_button);
            closeButton = (ImageButton) floatingView.findViewById(R.id.close_button);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
            params.x = 0;
            params.y = 100;


            windowManager.addView(floatingView, params);
...
```

[left is the first time, right is when stop and re open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGGMi.png)

Comment: can you show us screenshot of your prob to understand bit more

Comment: done! any idea?